# Form for group membership in web2py

Tags: web2py

web2py has a nice RBAC system as well as many built-in forms to manage users. I can't see to find one to manage group membership. I realize there's one in appadmin, but I need to use one in my app. Ideally, I'd like to see checkboxes for the different groups in the user registration/profile page.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything standard built in for this, but you could easily build your own using [Crud](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#CRUD), or even more easily with [SQLFORM.grid / SQLFORM.smartgrid](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#SQLFORM.grid-and-SQLFORM.smartgrid-%28experimental%29). For example:

```
def manage_groups():
    return dict(form=SQLFORM.grid(db.auth_membership))
```

or

```
def manage_users():
    return dict(form=SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.auth_users))
```

If you want to select multiple groups on a registration/profile page, that's a little more complicated, but still not too difficult. You'd have to add checkboxes or a multiselect to the form, and when the form is submitted, have some logic in the controller that handles the inserts into db.auth_membership based on the memberships selected.